# Kubernetes: Allow pod egress network traffic

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-networking

### Background

Just deployed my new Kubernetes cluster to Google Cloud. It's a private cluster - available only from the internal network. I connecting this cluster from `bastion` machine. With my `bastion` host, I can manage my cluster.

My cluster configuration:

[image]

### The Problem

It's seems like my pods doent have network to go out of the pod. for example:

```
$ curl google.com
```

Return error - unable to connect. So I logged the pod with SSH and tried to figure out what is the problem.

Two options that I can think of:

1. Firewall blocks all the egress traffic by default? I tried to allow it with new firewall rule that allow egress.
   [image]
   It's didn't solved the problem. (where `10.56.0.0/14` is my pods range)
2. My network dont have "default gateway" that allow internet access. I checked in "routers" area and it seems like it there:
   [image]

### Question

How to solved the issue and let my pods access to the internet freely?

Comment: As per [Virtual Private Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules), every network has two implied firewall rules, where the ‘implied allow egress rule’ permits outgoing connections and the ‘implied deny ingress rule’ blocks incoming connections. So, GCP firewall rules blocks all the ingress traffic by default, not the egress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the missing part.

> In the Kubernetes Engine Private Cluster model, your nodes have access
>   to the rest of your VPC private deployments, including private access
>   to Google managed services such as gcr.io, Google Cloud Storage and
>   Google BigQuery. Access to the internet isn’t possible unless you set
>   up additional mechanisms such as a NAT gateway.

[source](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-engine-private-clusters-now).

Adding NAT solved the issue!

Comment: Here's [simple instructions](https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-cloud-nat-with-gke-cluster-c82364546d9e) how to do it exactly.